# Is there a method to group 4 controls into an UserControl or template and use it in parent UserControl and bind them with MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm setting up an parent `usercontrol` that contains 4 controls(2 `checkbox` and 2 `textboxes`) in a row and those 4 `controls` are repeated like ten times verticaly down.
Instead of repeating this four control, is there a method to make it as another `usercontrol` and add it as a single control in the parent `usercontrol` and bind using the parent `viewmodel` in `MVVM`?

I thought of creating them as separate controls and it became a lot complex while looking at the code.

Parent `usercontrol` xaml

```
 <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,2.5,5,0" IsChecked="{Binding LeftChecked0, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,10" Text="{Binding LeftValue0, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>

            <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Margin="15,2.5,5,0" IsChecked="{Binding RightChecked0, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,10" Text="{Binding RightValue0, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>


            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,2.5,5,0" ></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,10"></TextBox>
            <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="15,2.5,5,0"></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,10"></TextBox>

            <Label Content="Degree" Grid.Row="2"/>

            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5,2.5,5,0" ></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,10"></TextBox>
            <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Margin="15,2.5,5,0"></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,10"></TextBox>

            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5,2.5,5,0" ></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,10"></TextBox>
            <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Margin="15,2.5,5,0"></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,10"></TextBox>

            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Margin="5,2.5,5,0" ></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,10"></TextBox>
            <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Margin="15,2.5,5,0"></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,10"></TextBox>

            <Label Content="Iteration" Grid.Row="6"/>

            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Margin="5,2.5,5,0" ></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,10"></TextBox>
            <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7" Margin="15,2.5,5,0"></CheckBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="7" Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,10"></TextBox>


        </Grid>
```

my parent viewmodel

```
 public class ControlVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        private bool leftChecked0;

        public bool LeftChecked0
        {
            get { return leftChecked0; }
            set
            {
                leftChecked0 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool rightChecked0;

        public bool RightChecked0
        {
            get { return rightChecked0; }
            set
            {
                rightChecked0 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        private string leftValue0;

        public string LeftValue0
        {
            get { return leftValue0; }
            set
            {
                leftValue0 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string rightValue0;

        public string RightValue0
        {
            get { return rightValue0; }
            set
            {
                rightValue0 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

As like in the above code sample of `viewmodel`, I'm supposed to create `properties` and `fields` for all the other 10 more rows.

I thought of adding it as an item template in `itemtemplate` control. but it wont suite for my problem as sometimes it is required to add other controls in-between each row of these four `controls`.

if there is a way to wrap the four `controls` into an `usercontrol` and call it in one line in xaml? In that case, how my `viewmodel` should be? and how the binding works between parent `viewmodel` and child `usercontrols`?

I expect to make it simple rather than defining many repeated lines of same `controls` and `properties`.

Comment: This sounds like you need to repeat a basic control for each item in a list?

Comment: @slugster yes. but sometimes, i need to add other controls in-between each row as like the label 'Degree'. but column should be same.

Comment: Then you could use a list control, and design a list item template that represents the look you want. And you can use a [data template selector](https://www.wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) to change which template is used for any particular list item.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you could handle this.

The first is to save just a bit of repetition by building a usercontrol. You put your checkboxes in it and expose dependency properties so you can set which properties these are supposed to set, text the user sees etc.

This usercontrol would then bind it's checkboxes using code.

You then put a bunch of these in an itemscontrol.

A bit like ( but different from ) this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29777.wpf-property-list-editing.aspx

Here I use a usercontrol called EditRow which encapsulates the common functionality I want.  That allows you to put content in it so you can have a checkbox, textbox or whatever. But the concept is similar.

Because you're adding these into your itemscontrol in the view, you can put something else wherever you like in there.

Want a Textblock, no problem.

You'll need some code in that usercontrol to do the bindings but you could retain however your data works at the moment unchanged.

The alternative is to template out viewmodels into UI.

You do so by binding an observablecollection to the itemssource of an itemscontrol.

Add viewmodels to that collection.

Each of which corresponds to a line.

You'd have a CheckBoxyIshvm, a Labelvm etc.

In the itemscontrol, you associate a template with viewmodel type using datatype=

That then templates out a labelvm into whatever you give it as a template for one of those.

You would of course then need to translate your collectionof ChecboxyIshVM into whatever you're doing with that data at the moment.

Hope that's clear.

I don't seem to be able to get insert a picture to work at the moment, but the latter approach is how I do the list of stuff with separators, titles and not-buttons here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEa5I.png